# Error on migration creating a new user - model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying to add my custom user models however, whenever I try to migration my changes I get an error:

```
account.EmailAddress.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
socialaccount.SocialAccount.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

In my settings I have already added:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

My custom user model is:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are the ForeignKey's to User defined? See the [Django docs on referencing the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) - note the use of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in ForeignKey fields

Comment: @elyas `allautth` is a Django package

Answer (score 1):

You've modified AUTH_USER_MODEL after having packages installed that referenced it. Now the references are wrong and you have to do some manual work [outlined in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project):

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and many-to-many relationships, for example.
>
> This change can’t be done automatically and requires manually fixing your schema, moving your data from the old user table, and possibly manually reapplying some migrations. See #25313 for an outline of the steps.

If you don't care about the data, because the project is not live yet, you can just drop your database, create a new empty database and migrate.

If neither of these options sound appealing, re-evaluate if you really need a custom user model - perhaps all you need to do is [extending it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).